# regex to add missing quotes

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am trying to add missing quotes at the ends of some lines in a text file.

I find that the regex [^\"]$ suffices to find lines with missing terminal doublequotes and so tried the following replacement using a backreference (which tbh I've never used before).  Using parens around the 'capture group' I hoped that sed would allow backreference to that group, but

```
sed  's|([^\"]$)|\1\"|g' bigfile.tsv
```

hits

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

and same if I don't escape the replacement quotes

```
sed  's|([^\"]$)|\1"|g' bigfile.tsv
```

(tho now its char 16 that's offensive) . How does the backreference go?   https://xkcd.com/1171/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run `sed` without `-E`, then the expression is a basic regular expression and the capture groups must be written as `\(...\)`.  When you use `-E` to enable extended regular expressions, capture groups are written `(...)`.

The `\` inside `[...]` is literal, so your expression would also avoid adding a double quote on lines ending with `\`.  Some of the other escaping is also unnecessary.

Therefore, you may write your `sed` command as

```
sed 's/\([^"]\)$/\1"/'
```

or as

```
sed -E 's/([^"])$/\1"/'
```

Or, using `&`:

```
sed 's/[^"]$/&"/'
```

The `&` in the replacement part of the expression will be substituted by the part of the input that matched the regular expression.

A couple of other alternatives that does not use a capture group:

```
sed '/[^"]$/ s/$/"/'
```

This applies `s/$/"/` to all lines that matches `/[^"]$/`.

Or, alternatively,

```
sed '/"$/ !s/$/"/'
```

This applies `s/$/"/` to all lines that don't match `/"$/` (there's a slight difference from the other approaches here in that it also adds a `"` to empty lines).

Note that in all cases, the `g` flag at the end is *definitely* not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, this cleared up some mysteries for me

Answer (score 2):

Try `sed -e 's|\([^\"]$\)|\1\"|g' bigfile.tsv`.

Comment: This still does not add the missing `"` to lines ending with backslash and it needlessly uses `g` at the end (an anchored expression can only match once).

Comment: I just provided a hint about the error message; I did not intend to solve the whole problem for the author. Mostly because I think the author will learn more when doing it himself or herself.

Comment: @U.Windl They may, or they may not ever notice.